# Filter and modify string in the list comprehention

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a code that filters elements in a list of string using list comprehentions. Like this:

```
def get_items(items):
    return [item for item in items if not item.startswidth('some_prefix') and not (item == 'bad_string' or item.endswith('bad_postfix') of 'bad_substr' in item) and not ites.endswidth('another_bad_postfix')]
```

And now I want not just filter, but also modificate item and for each item aply this ligic:

```
if item.startswith('./'):
  item = item[2:]
```

What is the pythonic way to do this? Obiously I can just rewrite this from comprehentions into simple loop like:

```
for item in items:
   res = []
   if not item.startswidth('some_prefix') and not (item == 'bad_string' or item.endswith('bad_postfix') of 'bad_substr' in item) and not ites.endswidth('another_bad_postfix'):
     break
   if item.startswith('./'):
     item = item[2:]
   res.append(item)
```

But it looks really ugly way. Is there more elegant one?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your logic, for example why would you `break` if your item is *not* "bad_string"? Or is "bad_string" an inappropriately named filler?

Comment: My bad, break should be opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cram that into the comprehension with:

```
return [item[2:] if item.startswith('./') else item for item in ...
```

Do note, however, that the comprehension written that way is a bit unreadable. You could separate out the items criterion in a separate function:

```
def item_is_good(item):
  return( not item.startswidth('some_prefix') and 
  not (item == 'bad_string' or 
       item.endswith('bad_postfix') of 
       'bad_substr' in item) and 
  not item.endswidth('another_bad_postfix') )
```

turning the comprehension in

```
[item[2:] if item.startswith('./') else item for item in items if item_is_good(item)]
```

Comment: Would the downvoter maybe clarify on the reason? Can't quite improve the answer if I don't know why they think it's bad

Answer (score 1):

I think this will look better:

```
def get_items(items):
    return [
        item[2:] if item.startswith('./') else item
        for item in items 
        if not item.startswidth('some_prefix') and not (item == 'bad_string' or item.endswith('bad_postfix') of 'bad_substr' in item) and not ites.endswidth('another_bad_postfix')
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `map()` and `filter()` methods to increase the readability of your code.
[Here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) you can find examples on map and filter methods.

First you can use the filter method to filter items on the list. Then you can use the map function to make the modification you want.

Comment: Yes, I understand that map and filter - are the best here. But I do not want to significally change this piece of code.

Answer (score -1):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
def get_items():
    return [item[2:] if item[:2] == './' else item for item in [your_list_comprehension] ]
```

Comment: So, do exactly what the other two answers say, but with one more loop over all items..?

Comment: This will do a full scan of `items` in the original `your_list_comprehension` (which is evaluated before the external one is started), then you loop over all the remaining items again to potentially remove the `./` at the beginning. There is no benefit in splitting these two operations in two different comprehensions and the time complexity doubles, it doesn't stay the same.

Comment: @GPhilo It looks neater and is more readable. Also, the time complexity stays the same as it's still O(N).

Comment: No, the time complexity *class* is the same, because O-notation ignores constant multipliers. The actual time complexity is `len(items) + len(your_list_comprehension )` which in the worst case is twice as much as doing everything in one go. Also, paste in the original list comprehension instead and you'll see this is really not neater, nor readable. The readable version is @stasdeep's